# SVG : xlink:href loaded image not working in safari

Tags: javascript, svg, xlink

I have load **base64encodeed** image to `'xlink:href'` attributes for `#patternImage` image tag. Its working fine in **Chrome** and **Firefox** but not working in **Safari**.

**Html :**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id='svgId' width="576" height="720" style="outline:auto;" >
    <defs>
        <pattern id="imgpattern" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <image id="patternImage" xlink:href="" width="20" height="20"></image>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <path id="svgpath" stroke="#f000" fill="#ff0000" stroke-width="0.25px" style="fill:url(#imgpattern) !important"></path>
</svg>
```

**JS :**

```
$("#patternImage").attr("xlink:href",encodedImage);
$("#patternImage").load(function(){
    console.log("Loaded");
});
```

Comment: Please show us a few more lines of your "HTML". How do you use the `<image>`? As part of a `<pattern>`? Also, what mimetype is the image you load? If it is an SVG, please also show that in unencoded form.

Comment: @ccprog `<image>` is a part of `<pattern>`

Comment: Which version of Safari? Works for me on 11.1.1 https://jsfiddle.net/2q93wu15/1/
Also, I'm joining @ccprog in requesting an [MCVE]. We need to know what's the image being set, and what's the actual path `d` is.

Comment: @Kaiido its also 11.1.1 and path `d` id dynamic like 'd="M 0,0 L 252,144 612,144 612,180 648,180 648,216 684,216 684,252 720,252 720,612 684,612 684,648 648,648 648,684 612,684 612,720 252,720 252,684 216,684 216,648 180,648 180,612 144,612 144,252 180,252 180,216 216,216 216,180 252,180 252,144 0,0 L 0,0 0,864 864,864 864,0 0,0"

Comment: *We need to know what's the image being set*. Even with this `d` attribute [it still works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/2q93wu15/2/). Can you confirm it doesn't for you?

Comment: @Kaiido Your example works in Safari. I will try as per your example. once done I will inform you. Any ways thank you so much

Comment: @Kaiido I get `base64image` source from html So I just want to load it from `src` attribute like `$("#patternImage").attr("xlink:href",$("#imgMat_2").attr('src'));` Please explain how to use `promises` for this

Comment: If you already have it, you don't need promises.

Comment: What answer? That I can not reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Kaiido I have tried same like `$("#patternImage").attr("xlink:href",$("#imgMat_2").attr('src'));` but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You [Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido)

The Solutions is :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id='svgId' width="576" height="720" style="outline:auto;">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="imgpattern" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <image id="patternImage" xlink:href="" width="20" height="20"></image>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <path id="svgpath" stroke="#f000" fill="#ff0000" stroke-width="0.25px" style="fill:url(#imgpattern)" d="M0,0H576V720H0z"></path>
</svg>
```

Javascript :

```
fetch("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg").then(r => r.blob())
  .then(b => new Promise(res => {
    const f = new FileReader();
    f.onload = e => res(f.result);
    f.readAsDataURL(b);
  }))
  .then(encodedImage => {
    $("#patternImage").attr("xlink:href", encodedImage);
    $("#patternImage").load(function() {
    });
  });
```

Comment: have you consider using URL.createObjectURL(blob) instead of a base64 string?

Comment: No, I have not tried with `URL.createObjectURL(blob)`

Comment: I can recommend it

Comment: @Endless thanks for the recommendation, I will use it next time.